# Parsing a dibbler log with syslog-ng to send it to a remote syslog server

Tags: syslog-ng

I'm setting up a syslog-ng (version 3.24.1), and I need it to handle the logs created by dibbler.
The ideia is to parse them and send them to a remote syslog server, where they can be filered.

This is for a embeded system running linux. I can't use python or the python parser

This is my configuration:

```
@version: 3.24

options { chain_hostnames(off); flush_lines(0); use_dns(no); dns-cache(no); use_fqdn(no);
owner(root); create-dirs(yes); perm(0640); stats_freq(0);
keep-timestamp(yes);threaded(yes); };

source s_dibbler {
    channel {
        source {
            wildcard-file(
                base-dir("/var/log/dibbler/")
                filename-pattern("*.log")
                flags(no-parse)
                default-facility(daemon)
            );
        };
        parser {
            csv-parser(
                columns("dibbler.date", "dibbler.time", "PROGRAM", "PRIORITY", "MESSAGE")
                delimiters(" ")
                flags(greedy, strip-whitespace)
            );
        };
        rewrite {
            set("dibbler-${PROGRAM}", value("PROGRAM"));
        };
        parser {
            date-parser (
                format("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")
                template("${dibbler.date} ${dibbler.time}")
                flags(guess-timezone)
                time-stamp(recvd)
            );
        };
    };
};

destination remote_server { syslog("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" transport("udp") port(4514) ); };

log { source(s_dibbler); destination(remote_server); };

template t_test_file { template(" \"${LEVEL}\" \n${MESSAGE}\n"); };
destination d_test_file { file("/var/log/test" template(t_test_file) ); };
log { source(s_dibbler); destination(d_test_file); };
```

This is a typical dibbler message:

```
2023.12.03 20:51:39 Server Notice    Parsing /etc/dibbler/server.conf config file...
2023.12.03 20:51:39 Server Error     Unable to bind socket (iface=brlan0/35, addr=ff02::1:2, port=547).
2023.12.03 20:51:39 Server Error     Low-level layer error message: Unable to bind socket: Address already in use
2023.12.03 20:51:39 Server Critical  Proper socket creation failed.
2023.12.03 20:51:39 Server Critical  Fatal error during TransMgr initialization.
```

Using the config I posted and with the example dibbler log I'm receiving:

```
Dec  3 20:51:39 <host> - NOTICE dibbler-Server[-] -    Parsing /etc/dibbler/server.conf config file... 
Dec  3 20:51:39 <host> - NOTICE dibbler-Server[-] -     Unable to bind socket (iface=brlan0/35, addr=ff02::1:2, port=547). 
Dec  3 20:51:39 <host> - NOTICE dibbler-Server[-] -     Low-level layer error message: Unable to bind socket: Address already in use 
Dec  3 20:51:39 <host> - NOTICE dibbler-Server[-] -  Proper socket creation failed. 
Dec  3 20:51:39 <host> - NOTICE dibbler-Server[-] -  Fatal error during TransMgr initialization.
```

On the "/var/log/test" (a temporary test output)

```
 "notice"
   Parsing /etc/dibbler/server.conf config file...
 "notice"
    Unable to bind socket (iface=brlan0/35, addr=ff02::1:2, port=547).
 "notice"
    Low-level layer error message: Unable to bind socket: Address already in use
 "notice"
 Proper socket creation failed.
 "notice"
 Fatal error during TransMgr initialization.
```

The LEVEL/PRIORITY (tried both) is not being set (The manual says that Hard-macros can't be set, but the config is valid, and I'm missing the point of the syslog-ng, if a user can write custom parsers, but can't change important variables (like this).

I'm also preaty sure that the log timestamp is wrong. But right now that is a minor thing.

PS. The server is running rsyslog, with the following template:

```
template(name="FileFormat" type="list") {
        property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3164" position.from="1" position.to="23")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="hostname")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="structured-data") #position.from="33" position.to="-1")
        constant(value=" ")
        #property(name="syslogfacility-text")
        #constant(value=" ")
        property(name="syslogseverity-text" caseConversion="upper")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="app-name")
        constant(value="[")
        property(name="procid")
        constant(value="] ")
        property(name="msgid")
        constant(value=" ")
        property(name="msg")
        constant(value=" ")
        constant(value="\n")
}
```